# Is it guarranteed that a webhook will be triggered *after* client-side Smart Payment Buttons .then()?

Tags: javascript, paypal, callback, webhooks

I am working on a website with a PayPal (checkout/REST API) integration that requires data from a form be saved to a database table. As far as I know, it is not possible to have PayPal send data gathered in a form to a webhook in order to save it to the DB. I am getting around this by first saving as pending, with the orderID, and then, in the webhook updating the record with the same orderID to not be pending.

However, this approach relies on the fact that the webhook is invoked after the saving to the database as pending (which is invoked on the client side via AJAX). This indeed *seems* to always be the case. Can I rely on the webhook being called second?

Here is the JavaScript code equivalent to what I am using:

```js
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        // Call your server to save the transaction
        return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID
          })
        });
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Will the AJAX call in `onApprove` reliably happen before the webhook is invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically yes, but I would hesitate to say "reliably", since to some extent you are depending on client-side behavior.

One alternative solution would be to pass the "CUSTOM" parameter during payment setup, which will be returned to you both after approval (in the details) and as part of the notification webhook.

Another alternative solution would be to integrate a server-side solution, e.g. the one in this skeleton demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  With this solution, no PayPal transaction is created until after the `fetch(` XHR to your server, which must then do a direct API call to paypal to capture the v2/order , and will receive an immediate API response of success/failure, and can then store all the necessary data in the data base in one atomic operation. A benefit of this server-side solution is it does not depend on asynchronous webhooks in any way. It is the most robust solution.

Comment: How robust is the first solution compared to the second? What is the likelihood of the first failing when the second would succeed?

Comment: Webhooks are a dependency for the first solution. So if the webhook service goes down or has any issue, this will interrupt your processing.  I much prefer solutions with fewer dependencies and things that can go wrong -- however if you've already implemented something using webhooks, it's not necessarily worth the trouble to change it right now

Comment: Could you please give a link to docs about or an explanation of how to use the CUSTOM parameter? I could not find any reference to it , and it would be very useful for what I am currently attempting.

Comment: For the v2/orders API used by Smart Payment Buttons, it's documented as the `custom_id` parameter to the `purchase_units` array: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request